# Definition of function can't be found when linking C object files

Tags: c, linker-errors

I met a problem when I built my project and I simplify it like below:

1. File `a.c` includes definition of function `f()`
2. File `a.h` includes declaration of function `f()`
3. File `b.c`, which includes `a.h`, calls function `f()`
4. Both `a.c` and `b.c` belong to one project `p`

But when the linker links a.o and b.o, it reports errors: `definition of f() can't be found (reference from b.o)`; could someone tell me what will cause the error happen?

Comment: @Mat: order of object files shouldn't matter; order of libraries does.

Comment: Despite your assertion 1 to the contrary, the linker doesn't think that `a.o` contains a definition of function `f()`.  You might look at the object file (with `nm` or `objtool` on Unix; I'm not sure of the equivalent on Windows), and see whether there actually is a definition of `f()` in `a.o`.

Comment: I have tried to call f() in a.c and it works, so I think definition of f() exists in a.c. The order of libraries you mentioned may be root cause, I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: Is f() defined as static?

Comment: Paste your link statement from your make file, or a reproducible configuration of said-same with your a.c and b.c files. Something isn't right.

Comment: An uneducated guess: some part of the prohect is C and some other is C++.

Comment: @n.m.: Your guess may be right.

Comment: @user3011988: Please post the some part of header file. It will help us to solve the problem.

Comment: Since both mcleod_ideafix and n.m. have said what I was going to suggest (+1 for both), we will only be able to tell you which is right (or if there is a third contender) if you give us the code and include your makefile or compilation command. We will particularly be interested in which compiler is used. If you're using an IDE please specify the IDE and the console info if you have it.

Comment: no, it's a pure c project and the function is not static. I will post information later.I prefer to Jonathan's suggestion but I'm busy with other tasks now. I will give result after I check the order of libs.Thank you all.